# Pass Value From MainWindow to UserControl

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-controls

I have a Simple Application, and I want to pass a variable from MainWindow to the UserControl.

Here is the Grid in my MainWindow, where I fit in my UserControl called Forrasok.

```
MainWindow.xaml

<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Name="Sources"></Grid>
```

Here is the MainWindow.xaml.vb

```
MainWindow.xaml.vb

For value AS Integer From 1 To 5

        Dim forras As New Forrasok
        Sources.Children.Add(forras)  //Pass value here somehow!

Next
```

My Usercontrol have a designed xaml, with some comboboxes. The goal is to pass an integer to the UserControl to create the same design with different combobox names.

```
Sources.xaml

<ComboBox Width="250" Height="25" Name="SomeName+value">
```

Comment: You can send it as `Tag` something like this `forras.Tag = 123`

Comment: Can you explain it how to use it? How can I get it at my UserControl?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear, but I did understand that you want to pass an `int` value from the `MainWindow` to the `UserControl`. The usual way to do this is to declare a property in your `UserControl`:

```
public int IntValue { get; set; }
```

Then, if you have access to the `UserControl` from `MainWindow`, you can simply do this:

```
YourUserControl.IntValue = yourIntValue;
```

If you want to be able to data bind to the property, then you'll need to declare a `DependencyProperty` instead. You can find out how to do that in the [Dependency Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN, but you would then be able to do this in XAML:

```
<YourXmlNamespacePrefix:YourUserControl IntValue="{Binding IntValueFromMainWindow}" />
```

Comment: If I send you an example picture will it help?